# Is there an easy way to output two columns to the console in Java?

Tags: java

As the title says, is there an easy way to output two columns to the console in Java?

I'm aware of `\t`, but I haven't found a way to space based on a specific column when using printf.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the width and precision specifiers, set to the same value. This will pad strings that are too short, and truncate strings that are too long. The '-' flag will left-justify the values in the columns.

```
System.out.printf("%-30.30s  %-30.30s%n", v1, v2);
```

Comment: More details on Java string formatting in [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: What's the difference between `%-30.30s` and `%-30s`?

Comment: @JohnRPerry With .30, the maximum field width is 30. Longer values will be truncated.

Comment: But for this kind of statement we can't apply that.

`str += "\t " + item.getName() + " [" + item.getValue()
                     + "]" + "\t" + item.getDescription()+ "\n"; `
what should we do for this situation?

Comment: @chamzz.dot Use `String.format()` instead of concatenating strings. It looks like you are using that in a loop which can have quadratic time complexity (in other words, that's bad). Instead, make `str` a `StringBuilder` outside your loop, and `append()` the result of each `String.format()` call inside the loop.

Answer (score 32):

i did it without using Formatter class as :

```
 
System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", "osne", "two", "thredsfe");
System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", "one", "tdsfwo", "thsdfree");
System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", "onsdfe", "twdfo", "three");
System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", "odsfne", "twsdfo", "thdfree");
System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", "osdne", "twdfo", "three");
System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", "odsfne", "tdfwo", "three");
```

and output was

```
osne       two        thredsfe  
one        tdsfwo     thsdfree  
onsdfe     twdfo      three     
odsfne     twsdfo     thdfree   
osdne      twdfo      three     
odsfne     tdfwo      three
```

Answer (score 16):

Late answer but if you don't want to hardcode the width, how about something that works like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Columns()
        .addLine("One", "Two", "Three", "Four")
        .addLine("1", "2", "3", "4")
        .print()
    ;
}
```

And displays:

```
One Two Three Four 
1   2   3     4
```

Well all it takes is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;  

public class Columns {

    List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> maxLengths = new ArrayList<>();
    int numColumns = -1;

    public Columns addLine(String... line) {

        if (numColumns == -1){
            numColumns = line.length;
            for(int column = 0; column < numColumns; column++) {
                maxLengths.add(0);
            }
        }

        if (numColumns != line.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        for(int column = 0; column < numColumns; column++) {
            int length = Math
                .max( 
                    maxLengths.get(column), 
                    line[column].length() 
                )
            ;
            maxLengths.set( column, length );
        }

        lines.add( Arrays.asList(line) );

        return this;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println( toString() );
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result = "";
        for(List<String> line : lines) {
            for(int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
                result += pad( line.get(i), maxLengths.get(i) + 1 );                
            }
            result += System.lineSeparator();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String pad(String word, int newLength){
        while (word.length() < newLength) {
            word += " ";            
        }       
        return word;
    }
}
```

Since it won't print until it has all the lines, it can learn how wide to make the columns. No need to hard code the width.

Comment: I'm kinda new in Java, and I'm confused in how your methods communicate with each other. `pad()` and `System.lineSeparator()` and this line `maxLengths.set(  i, Math.max( maxLengths.get(i), line[i].length() )` what exactly does this do? Sorry for the barrage of questions. I just don't like using code that I do not know how it works exactly.

Comment: @Wax ok. Better?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.
Although wouldn't it be better to better to use `StringBuilder` here instead of string concatenation?
I know the purpose of this solution isn't to target that issue, but still it'd be better to use `StringBuilder` here, since String concatenation is very expensive.