# How to create a tab delimited in Eclipse Java

Tags: java, tabs, delimited

I'm trying to make my result looks good by having a good tab for each column result.
Here's my toString() function. I searched for this problem in stackoverflow, but it doesn't answer my question. I can't find the StringUtils.rightPad(String, int) utilities in Eclipse Java. Should I download any package or anything?

```
         public String toString(){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(150);
        sb.append(getDept(department));
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append(getName());
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append(getAge());
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append(checks.check());

        return sb.toString();
    }


Here's my result using ("\t") :

Department      Name    Age Prime
__________________________________________________
Information_Systems Hacking Novice  23  true
Accounting  Counting Novice 25  false
Marketing   Sales Savvy 38  false
Information_Systems Hacking Savvy   38  false
Accounting  Counting Savvy  40  false
Accounting  Counting Pro    45  false
Information_Systems Hacking Pro 46  false
Human_Resources Hiring Pro  47  true
Marketing   Sales Pro   48  false
Marketing   Sales Guru  50  false
Information_Systems Hacking Guru    51  false
Accounting  Counting Guru   55  false
Human_Resources Hiring Guru 58  false
```

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with Eclipse? You are just looking for ways to properly pad your strings, is it not so.

Comment: Look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699878/is-there-an-easy-way-to-output-two-columns-to-the-console-in-java

Comment: It works printf but not append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.rightPad(String, int)
```

[Download Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi)

Comment: How can I import to the package into my Eclipse?

Comment: You need to add the commons-lang library to your project. The way how to do that, depends on dependency system you use, eg. for maven add `<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>` to your pom, for ivy: `<dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.6" conf="default" />` to ivy.xml. And if you don't use any dependency tool, just download the library and add as dependency to your project (Project --> Properties --> Java build Path --> Libraries --> Add JARS.../Add External JARs)