# How do I output data that is read from a .txt file in tabular format in Java?

Tags: java, input, output, tabular

I need to write a program for my class that requires I have the program read the data from a .txt file then list out each number, while keeping a running total of the sum of those numbers, average out the numbers, then display them on the console and output them to a .txt file.  What I'm having trouble with is formatting the output to be tabular.  I can't seem to figure out how to get this data into a two column format, one for the original numbers and one for the running total.

Here's what I have so far on that part of it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class SeanPeck_2_04 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  // Declare variables
    // Define your file names 
    final String INPUT_FILE  = ("/Users/copmuter/Input.txt");
    final String OUTPUT_FILE = ("/Users/computer/Output.txt");

  int numberOfNumbers = 0; // Number of numbers in the input file
    double sum = 0;          // The sum of the numbers
  double average = 0;      // The average of the numbers read
    double oneNumber;            // An individual number read from the file
  double runningTotal = 0;      // the running total sum of the numbers

  // Access the input/output files
    File inputDataFile = new File(INPUT_FILE);
    Scanner inputFile  = new Scanner(inputDataFile);
    FileWriter outputDataFile = new FileWriter(OUTPUT_FILE);
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(outputDataFile);
  System.out.println("Reading  file " + INPUT_FILE + "\r\n" +
                       "Creating file " + OUTPUT_FILE);

    // Read the input file and sum the numbers. 

    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            numberOfNumbers++;
            oneNumber = inputFile.nextDouble();
        sum += oneNumber;             //Calculate total sum of numbers
            runningTotal += oneNumber;    // Calculate the running total

        System.out.printf("%.2f %.2f", oneNumber, runningTotal, "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want format the output in two columns you can use

> %-10.2f\t%.2f\n

Notice the -10 is the size of the column.

If you need more examples look at

[Is there an easy way to output two columns to the console in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699878/is-there-an-easy-way-to-output-two-columns-to-the-console-in-java)

Comment: Thank you!  Yeah, I checked out that thread, but still couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong.  But this worked.