# how to use printf to print in a table form

Tags: java, printf

i want to print some thing like this:

```
===================================================================================================

       Section 1              Section 2           Section 3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1110 - Ahmed Sami - Active         1116 - Maher Alsolami - Active    1122 - Waleed Alamri - Active
1111 - Mohammed Turkey - Active    1117 - Mohanned Sami - Active     1123 - Sami Alghamdi - Active
1112 - Sami Omer - Active          1118 - Feras Ahmed - Active       1124 - Majed Alharbi - Active
1113 - Bander Ali - Active         1119 - Nawaf Algarni - Active     1125 - Anwar Aljohani - Active
1114 - Basem Alzahrani - Active    1120 - Fahad Alharthi - Active    1120 - Fahad Alharthi - Active 
1115 - Turkey Almutairi - Active   1121 - Anas Batarfi - Active
==================================================================================================
```

but i get this :

```
===================================================================================================

       Section 1              Section 2           Section 3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1110 - Ahmed Sami - Active 1116 - Maher Alsolami - Active 
1111 - Mohammed Turkey - Active 1117 - Mohanned Sami - Active 
1112 - Sami Omer - Active 1118 - Feras Ahmed - Active 
1113 - Bander Ali - Active 1119 - Nawaf Algarni - Active 
1114 - Basem Alzahrani - Active 1120 - Fahad Alharthi - Active 
1115 - Turkey Almutairi - Active 1121 - Anas Batarfi - Active 
==================================================================================================
```

here is the code i use (the code does give an error in the end i just want to know how can sorted like the first table):

```
System.out.println("\nThe first distribution for students among the available sectios ");
System.out.println("===================================================================================================\n"
    + "\n"
    + "       Section 1           Section 2           Section 3\n"
    + "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   System.out.printf("%s%s%s%s", students[i].getStudID() + " - ", students[i].getFname() + " ", students[i].getLname() + " - ", students[i].getStatus() + " ");
   System.out.printf("%s%s%s%s", students[i + 6].getStudID() + " - ", students[i + 6].getFname() + " ", students[i + 6].getLname() + " - ", students[i + 6].getStatus() + " ");
   System.out.printf("%s%s%s%s", students[i + 12].getStudID() + " - ", students[i + 12].getFname() + " ", students[i + 12].getLname() + " - ", students[i + 12].getStatus() + " ");
   System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: read up on how printf formatting works.  "%20s" will always print 20 characters.  Start with that.  That might be all you need to know if you can hard code your column widths.

Comment: And `"%-20s"` to align on the left, while `"%20s"` aligns on the right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java printf formatting to print items in a table or columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466526/java-printf-formatting-to-print-items-in-a-table-or-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `%s%s%s%s`, use sufficient space for individual parts e.g. in the following statement, `%6s%20s%20s%20s` reserves a 6 characters-wide space for `students[i].getStudID()`, 20 characters-wide space for `students[i].getFname()`, 20 characters-wide space for `students[i].getLname()`, and 10 characters-wide space for `students[i].getStatus()`.

```
System.out.printf("%6s%20s%20s%10s", students[i].getStudID() + " - ", students[i].getFname() + " ", students[i].getLname() + " - ", students[i].getStatus() + " ");
```

You can adjust the required space as per your requirement.

Learn more about it from the documentation of [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). You can also check [this](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples) for some more examples and explanation.