# Creating a Call Simulator

Tags: java

The number of calls received per minute at a Help Desk has been estimated to be between 5 and 10.

Write a simulation program that simulates calls arriving at the Help Desk for a period of 12 hours and output the frequency of calls during this period.

Sample output: 
(Note: The frequencies for your program will be different from the ones shown below. Each time you run your program, you should get different frequencies)

Calls/Minute          Frequency

5                      155

6                      172

7                      148

8                      123

9                        62

10                      60

This is what I've came up with, but cannot figure out how to split/leave a gap between calls/minute and frequency. Basically splitting it into two rows.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class randomCalls {

   /**

   * @param args

   */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Random rn = new Random();
       int n;
       for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)
       {

 n = rn.nextInt(6) +5;

       System.out.println("Calls/Minute" +"\n" + n);

       System.out.print(' ');

       System.out.println(" Frequency" + "\n"+ i);

       }
   }

}
```

Comment: Do _you_ know what you're asking? Because I don't.

Comment: SPLIT INTO 2 ROWS. 1 ROW DISPLAYS THE CALLS/MINUTE OTHER ROW DISPLAYING FREQUENCY.

Comment: Doesn't `"\n"` solve your problem?

Comment: it doesn't display it like it shows in the sample run

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you are trying to print out Calls/Minute and Frequency in columns. Here is a [helpful link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699878/is-there-an-easy-way-to-output-two-columns-to-the-console-in-java)

In order to use that method your need to...

1. Combine the lines `System.out.println("Calls/Minute" +"\n" + n);` and `System.out.println(" Frequency" + "\n"+ i);`, and format the resulting single line so that it is split into two columns.

   ```
   //Example
   System.out.printf("%-12.30s %-30.30s%n","Column 1","Column 2");
   ```
2. Place it BEFORE your for loop (or else it will print every time)
3. Within your for loop, format your output exactly the same as you did the line in step one.

   ```
   //Example
   System.out.printf("%-12.30s %-30.30s%n",n,i);
   ```

Sample output in your program would look like this:

```
Calls/Minute Frequency                     
6            1                             
7            2                             
8            3                             
8            4                             
9            5                             
6            6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it to print like described:

> Random rn = new Random();

```
int n;
for(int i=1;i<=6;i++) {
    n = rn.nextInt(6) +5;
    System.out.println( n + " " + i );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also your line breaks "\n" will send the next values you tell your code to print to the next line. Line breaks are great for formatting but not so much for the columns you are trying to create.