# Aligning elements vertically below each other

Tags: java, alignment

I'm trying to align the columns exactly below each other using "\t" the the results are imperfect. 
Since this is for a rookie project we're not allowed to use JTable.
What else can I use here? I'm fresh out of ideas. 
Thanks!
There's a picture here:

[image: The output.]

And the code used for the output section:

```
    System.out.println("\n---------------------------------------------HERE 
    ARE YOUR DETAILS:--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Name - "+OB1.name);
    System.out.println("Address - "+OB1.address);
    System.out.println("Sum Assured\t\tTerm\t\tAge\t\tInterest 
    Earned\t\tAmount Paid" );
    System.out.println("\u20B9"+P+"\t\t"+T+"\t\t"+OB1.age+"\t\t\u20B9"+ 
    (int)interest+"\t\t\u20B9"+(int)A);
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
```

Comment: Post. Your. Code. The screenshot of the result is not helpful on its own.

Comment: What about the `framework` used to implement the frontend.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, are you actually writing a console application? You should edit your question to include a more clear description of what you're doing. Possible also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699878/is-there-an-easy-way-to-output-two-columns-to-the-console-in-java

Comment: Use a [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) with a mono-spaced font.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that! Edited and posted the code segment of the output.

Comment: Nah, this isn't a console application

Answer (score 0):

You could use padded string

```
int columnWidth = 15;
char fill = ' '; 
String userName = "Narendra"; 
String padded = new String(new char[columnWidth - userName.length()]).replace('\0', fill) + userName; 
System.out.println(padded);
```